# 'logonType' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, impersonation

Trying to use the SimpleImpersonation nuget package (https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/SimpleImpersonation) getting error in title.  Am I missing using statement?

```
var credentials = new UserCredentials(domain, username, password);
var result = Impersonation.RunAsUser(credentials, logonType, () =>
{
    return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( @"\\server\share" );
});
```

Comment: how have you declared logonType and is it available in this scope?

Comment: no i didnt can you provide example of declaring that?

Comment: It's LogonType enum. See line 28 in https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/SimpleImpersonation/blob/master/test/SimpleImpersonation.UnitTests/ImpersonationTests.cs as example.